# using variables in bazel WORKSPACE script

Tags: bazel

I'm using a bazel WORKSPACE file that is shared among several users. Each user needs to use his respective home directory path inside the WORKSPACE file.

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    path = "/home/some_specific_username/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/21.3.6528147",
)
```

Is there a way to replace `some_specific_username` by a variable? Something like

```
android_ndk_repository(
    name = "androidndk",
    path = "/home/$USER/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/21.3.6528147",
)
```

which would be whatever the current bash value of "$USER" is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android_ndk_repository` will read the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` environment variable if `path` is not set, so you can remove `path` and have each user set that environment variable. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/android.html#android_ndk_repository.path